# Where is the official website of the JTS project?

Tags: jts-topology-suite

I'm using the JTS API, published at http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/JTSHome.htm
However, there is another JTS API, published at http://sourceforge.net/projects/jts-topo-suite/

The former is version 1.8, from 2006.
The latter is version 1.13, from 2013.

I don't understand. What is the right version of JTS to use?
If the right version is at www.vividsolutions.com, then is this project alive? There are no new features there since 2006.

Comment: Make sure to read the [history of JTS and GEOS](http://tsusiatsoftware.net/jts/jts-history.html) from the documentation section of the link in blah238's answer. It explains Vivid Solutions' former role in JTS.

Comment: I rolled back the tag edit because `javatopologysuite` does not correspond to the legal name of the project. See the copyright note on the homepage.

Comment: @GeoKevin So Vivid Solutions' distribution is obsolete?

Comment: I don't have an official answer, but it would appear that yes, Vivid Solutions' distro is obsolete. @blah328 thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The official website of the JTS Topology Suite API is http://tsusiatsoftware.net/jts/main.html

This points to the [SourceForge page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jts-topo-suite/) as the official download site and source repository.